# How do I relate tables in Azure Mobile Service - Javascript Backend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, azure-mobile-services

On the azure page I can create my tables but there are only 4 data types and no option to create or relate the tables using foreign keys and SQL.

What I want to do is have a user and contact table with userId in contact table as a foreign key.

I am using apache cordova and angularJs on the front end in visual studio. I have already added the mobile service to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile Services does not directly support relationships in the backend, but you can customize the data using [server scripts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/#working-with-tables) and the [mssql object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/jj554212.aspx). Alternatively, you can create database views that have relationships between tables.

For an example of mapping relationships using database views, please see my post in this forum thread: [Best Practice For Syncing Related Tables in Offline Mode](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4c056373-d5cf-4ca6-9f00-f152d2b01372/best-practice-for-syncing-related-tables-in-offline-mode?forum=azuremobile#0e23494c-1da2-4ee3-ac5a-6955d0dfed3e).

For more information on managing the database directly, see this article: [Scale mobile services backed by Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-sql-scale-guidance/).